# Accessing something inside JSON array

Tags: python, json

I'm new to `JSON` and `python` and can't seem to figure this one out:

so I have this `JSON` file:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "Blank256#7156": [
                {
                    "money": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "sp01#2413": [
                {
                    "money": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to get the **money value of a user through python** with this code:

```
  name = ctx.message.author
  nam = str(name)
  with open('users.json') as out:
    
    dat = json.load(out)
    
    i = 0
    for x in dat["users"]:
      try:
        
         print(dat['users'][i][nam][0])
         return
      except:
        i += 1
```

This code allows me to get `dat['users'][i][nam]` but not the money which I think should be `dat['users'][i][nam][0]`

any advice?

Comment: Did you mean: ‘dat['users'][i][nam][0][“money”]’ ?

Comment: Firstly ily, secondly i hate my life

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to iterate over the users:

```py
name = ctx.message.author
nam = str(name)
with open('users.json') as out:
    
    dat = json.load(out)
    
    for d in dat["users"]:
        if nam in d:
            print(d[nam][0][“money”])
```

Comment: You sold it in you comment :)